# Obj-C SMS with hyperlink in it

Tags: objective-c, hyperlink

I would like to have the message body populate with a link in it, without showing the link, but instead a word.

Much like:

```
a href="http://www.google.com">Actual Text Shown</a>
```

.

Right now I have:

```
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text blah
  blah:\n%@\n\nSent by the Test app.", _Label.text];
```

Which comes out like this:

```
Some Text blah Blah:
label text

Sent by the Test app.
```

And I would like 'Test' to be hyperlinked to the app store.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the text of `_Label.text`? Is it just "label text" or does it contain a link?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done, SMS has no concept of hyperlinks.

Comment: So the only way to provide a link is to put the actual url in the message?